# Find complete string starting with a word from request response

Tags: python, regex, python-requests, python-re

How can I fetch complete line matching a word from the request object

For example I have response=request.get(url) and print(response.text) and suppose if the output has following lines, I am trying to fetch complete word starting with file_path and expected result as "file_path: /opt/temp"

user: abcd
search_file: f-abc-123
file_path: /opt/temp
branch: develop
email_to: abc@gmail.com
version: 1.10.00

Below is my code which seems to be not working

```
import re
import requests
response=request.get("https://artifactory.com",header=(..),verify=False)
res=re.search(r'file_path\w+',response.text)
print(res.group(0))
```

Output that I got:
file_path

Expected output:
file_path: /opt/temp

Comment: Add your output and expected output as well

Comment: And check your URL schema.

Comment: try`res = re.search(r'file_path: .*',item).group(0) `

Comment: @KlausD. This looks like a structured response to me.
Can you print response.json() and also type(response.json()) and see if that's a dict?
If Yes, then you can simply access by key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to parse line by line and make sure you get the whole line if it matches your string, then you can split your text output along newlines and check each line for the text you're looking for like

```
r = requests.get("https://artifactory.com",header=(..),verify=False)
lines = r.text.split('\n')
for line in lines:
  if 'file_path' in line:
    print(line)
```

However, if the data you're getting back is in json format which I suspect it may be from your description above, then you should definitely take advantage of the json format to process it instead of parsing line by line.  You can refer to the key for file_path in the json response like

```
r = requests.get("https://artifactory.com",header=(..),verify=False)
data = r.json()
print('file_path: ' + data['file_path'])
```

These approaches do not require regular expressions. The json approach is the best if you know you're dealing with json responses and not just some text response in an unknown format.

Comment: I tried the first way and it works fine. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```py
#until a newline(\n) is hit, consider all characters.
res= re.search(r'file_path[^\n]+', response.text)
print(res.group(0))
```

> output: 'file_path: /opt/temp'

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out